# Put navbar next to logo in white box with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have my logo on the left with a white background in the header but my navbar keeps going underneath this on the right. I don't understand why this is happening. Also I don't think my navbar list is going straight across.

```css
body {
 background-color: #832040;
 
}
.navbar-default {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.navbar ul.nav li a {
 font-family: 'Righteous', sans-serif;
 font-size: 38px;
 color: #000;
 padding: 25px;
 margin: 0;
}
.navbar ul.nav li a:hover {
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
 height: 40px;
}
.logo {
 width: 320px;
 padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-default">
<div class="logo">
 <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><img src="HairSite/KatiesKuts-Logo.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar nav pull-right">
             <ul class="nav navabar-nav">
                 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="appt.html">Appointments</a></li>
                     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't define any bootstrap rows or columns so your navbar is displaying below your logo and taking 100% width. You must define one row and two columns to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

you have missed out some proper html structure and classes bootstrap requires.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><img src="HairSite/KatiesKuts-Logo.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
                <li><a href="appt.html">Appointments</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

you could refer the following links for further references;

[Logo Nav by Start Bootstrap](https://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-logo-nav/)

[Navbar example form Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/)

Comment: I have used bootstrap version 3.3.5. Depending on the bootstrap version the structure and classes might change the bit. If so just let me know the bootstrap version.

Answer (score 1):

This might help or give you some ideas. You're missing some HTML and I don't believe `navbar-default` was a class in [2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar).

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: #832040;
}
.navbar .navbar-inner {
  background: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar .navbar-inner .nav > li > a {
  font-family: 'Righteous', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.navbar .navbar-inner .btn-navbar {
  margin-top: 45px;
}
.navbar .navbar-inner .nav > li > a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar .navbar-inner .nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <a class="brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x100/000">
      </a>

      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="appt.html">Appointments</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```